# Different effect when using plural method on Collection field with and without @Singular annotation

Tags: java, lombok

I want to have immutable myClass objects. Good solution seams to be using @Singular annotation.
The problem is when I use this annotation the method elements() appends elements to existing list, instead of creating the new one:

Let's assume that that we have:

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class MyClass  {
    @Singular
    private List<String> elemets;
}
```

and

```
MyClass.builder()
.elemets(Arrays.asList("elem1"))
.elemets(Arrays.asList("elem2"))
.build();
```

Without @Singular annotation we have elem2 on the list
with @Singular annotation we have both elem1 and elem2, if I want to have elem2 only I have to use clearElements() before.

Why implementation is different? Is it possible to use @Singular with my own implementation?

With @Singular annotation I cannot implement elemets(List elemets) method in MyClassBuilder class because I get: "Manually adding a method that @Singular @Builder would generate is not supported. If you want to manually manage the builder aspect for this field/parameter, don't use @Singular."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say that using `@Singular` isn't necessarily the best solution -- it depends on your use case. 
However, in most cases where you want to ensure immutability on classes that use collections, it is a good choice.

`@Singular` behaves the way it does because the Lombok designers decided that it's a good choice to do so. And I agree: It makes the two setter methods behave similarly; and in those rare cases where you want to reset the elements in a builder, you have the `clear` method.

`@Singular` generates pretty complex code (see https://projectlombok.org/features/BuilderSingular for an example). This is to ensure properties like efficiency and immutability (also when reusing builders to produce several objects). When you mess around with that code, you can easily violate these properties. Lombok prevents you from doing that.

If you really want to modify this aspect, you have three choices:

- `delombok` the builder code, copy it into your class, and modify it.
- Add another differently named method, like `clearAndSetElements(List<String>)`. But that's probably even more confusing.
- Remove `@Singular` and implement the setter methods on your own. You will have to put some effort in the implementation if you want the properties of Lombok's implementation; you can use the `delombok`ed code as inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1. In the first option I would have to give up the advantages of Lombok.
2. Because my task is to make the class objects immutable, and the class is already in use (with some fields with Singular annotation), I decided not to add any extra method. 
I got rid of Singular annotation and implement of my own  elemets() and element() methods as part of the static MyClassBuilder class. In those methods I create a new immutableList each time. 

I also did my own implementation of the getter method so that It return empty ImmutableList instead of NULL (to prevent NPE).

Comment: Yes, you can do that, too. I added your solution to my answer.

Comment: Be aware with `toBuilder = true` attribute on `@Builder` annotation! Adding `@Singular` annotation to existing code will change the behavioral.